# How do you acquire the Bronze Badge and Popular Question badge?

Tags: support, badges, tag-badges

#### Quote from wiki

> `Bronze Badge` - You must have a total score of 100 in at least 20 non-community wiki answers to achieve this badge.

#### Question

Does this mean you have to have a total score of 100 at each of these questions or is it about the score alltogether?

#### Quote from wiki

> `Popular Question` - Asked a question with 1,000 views. This badge can be awarded multiple times.

#### Question

Does this mean that you receive this badge for every 1000 views on a question or for every question that has a 1000 views or more?

Comment: Those are two different questions, but both answered in the faq. Next time please ask one question at a time. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get the bronze tag badge for a score of 100 counting all answers of yours having that tag.

You get a popular badge for a question only once.